# How do I implement drag and drop in my game?

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I have been looking all over SOF and online tutorials, but for some reason I still can't get it to work. I want to implement a drag and drop functionality in my game. Here is the activity:
[image: Game]

I want to be able to drag and drop the 4 shapes in the bottom. If the correct shape fits, I want the shape with the "?" to change into the correct shape. Can someone show me how I can do this?

Here is my code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int n;
ImageView shape1, shape2, shape3, shape4, guessShape;
ImageButton exit;
private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
Random rand = new Random();
ImageView[] shapes = new ImageView[4];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    //declare each imageview
    shape1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shape1);
    shape2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shape2);
    shape3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shape3);
    shape4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shape4);
    guessShape = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.guessShape);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    //add each imageView to the shapes[] array
    shapes[0] = shape1;
    shapes[1] = shape2;
    shapes[2] = shape3;
    shapes[3] = shape4;

    //store all the shapes in an array
    int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.img_0, R.drawable.img_1, R.drawable.img_2, R.drawable.img_3, R.drawable.img_4,
            R.drawable.img_5, R.drawable.img_6, R.drawable.img_7, R.drawable.img_8, R.drawable.img_9, R.drawable.img_10,
            R.drawable.img_11, R.drawable.img_12, R.drawable.img_13, R.drawable.img_14, R.drawable.img_15, R.drawable.img_16,
            R.drawable.img_17};

    //store all the guessShapes in an array
    int[] outlines = new int[]{R.drawable.outline_0, R.drawable.outline_1, R.drawable.outline_2,
            R.drawable.outline_3, R.drawable.outline_4, R.drawable.outline_5, R.drawable.outline_6,
            R.drawable.outline_7, R.drawable.outline_8, R.drawable.outline_9, R.drawable.outline_10,
            R.drawable.outline_11, R.drawable.outline_12, R.drawable.outline_13, R.drawable.outline_14,
            R.drawable.outline_15, R.drawable.outline_16, R.drawable.outline_17};

    //generate 4 random images from the array's and ensure that they don't match each other
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        list.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    int whichImg = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 4));
    int img1 = list.get(0);
    int img2 = list.get(1);
    int img3 = list.get(2);
    int img4 = list.get(3);

    if (whichImg == 1) {
        whichImg = img1;
    } else if (whichImg == 2) {
        whichImg = img2;
    } else if (whichImg == 3) {
        whichImg = img3;
    } else {
        whichImg = img4;
    }

    int outlineID = outlines[whichImg];

    //set the shape in each imageview
    guessShape.setBackgroundResource(outlineID);
    shape1.setBackgroundResource(images[img1]);
    shape2.setBackgroundResource(images[img2]);
    shape3.setBackgroundResource(images[img3]);
    shape4.setBackgroundResource(images[img4]);

    //ensures that 1/4 shape has the guess shape correspondence
    final Object currentBackground = guessShape.getBackground().getConstantState();

    //for loop to have the guess shape and 1/4 shapes to match
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        if (currentBackground.equals(getResourceID("outline_" + i, "drawable", getApplicationContext()))) {
            int random = new Random().nextInt(shapes.length);
            shapes[random].setBackgroundResource(getResourceID("img_" + i, "drawable", getApplicationContext()));
        }

        //set tags for each view
        guessShape.setTag("gShape");
        shape1.setTag("S_1");
        shape2.setTag("S_2");
        shape3.setTag("S_3");
        shape4.setTag("S_4");

    }
}


//method to get the ID of an image in drawable folder
protected final static int getResourceID(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
            ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
                    ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
                (
                        "No resource string found with name " + resName
                );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Although you were not clear enough.

Try this, First make a class that implements `onTouchListener`

```
    private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                    view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then define a drag listener

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // do nothing
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now simply use these lines

```
findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

**and**

```
findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
```

Here are some tutorials that might help you

[Tutorialpoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_drag_and_drop.htm)

[Link 2](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality--mobile-14402)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried implementing it but I get 'startDrag' deprecated??

Comment: same with "setBackgroundDrawable", it is deprecated?? sorry im new to android i dont know what this means, theres a line that goes through it

Comment: also, you declared two drawables entershape and normalshape, but the truth is, the shape with "?" can be a possible 18 shapes as seen in my code in the "outline" array, and the bottom 4 shapes can be any shape from the "images" array. So i cant really declare one image

Comment: ignore all the lines that have "setBackgroundDrawable", you only have to check weather its working or not, and about shapes, it doesn't matter that if you have an array of images, just use the logic on image view

Comment: Okay the drag is working but when I drop the drag my app crashes. This is because there is a line u did declaring a linear layout. I don't have a linear layout in my app. How do I fix this?

Comment: @AzIslam simply remove that line, the things that you dont have in your xml simply remove those lines and it will work fine

Comment: I did that, the drag works perfectly, however the 'guessShape' at the top doesn't change when the correct shape is dragged. Also, the 4 shapes at the bottom, when they're dragged, they don't go back to their original shape if its the wrong shape, they just disappear.

Comment: @AzIslam for this you have to implement your own logic as per your scenerio, e.g if the answer is wrong then simple restore images to original space, store their original state some where, then restore

Comment: I understand that Abdul however I was hoping for an answer that relates to my scenario as this is why I put the code in my question.

Comment: @AzIslam developers here only help you in solving your problems, they dont really solve your problem, and that do depends on how big the problem is, if its a small one, yeah developers do give exact solutions but for lengthy problems they only give the steps, i hope you do understand that